# Merge with duplicate record

Tags: sql, merge

I am having duplicates in my source. I am using max and group by in the values on the insert in SQL.

it is returning multiple rows and sql is not able to pick max..

```
VALUES 
((Select max(SOURCE.Id) from T1 group by 
PathID,id,monthid))
```

I want max values of duplicate and insert in to sql using merge.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: you are grouping Id again, if you include the column name in `group by`, you wont get desired results.

Comment: Why are you grouping by those columns? Do you just want the max source.ID? If you want to merge/update you need to add those columns in the select and join on them.

Comment: I have composite key and grouping by them to have multiple rows. source.id and id in the group by is different.  Source is having values like---Source.ID, PathID, id and month id....12,23,2,24........14,23,2,24,,,,,,,,,16,23,2,24.....I want 16 or 12 to be inserted in target.